# How to edit take folders for multiple tracks at once

Tags: logic-pro, drum

I have a drum recording with 6 mics and 10 takes. Is there a way to make Logic use the take selection from any of these tracks for all of them, if that makes sense? Basically, I want to be able to chose from different takes at different sections, but I want the take selection to then "propagate" to all the drum mic tracks.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is when you need Pro Tools to do this type of editing. Not sure about Logic but it usually falls over when it comes to fast editing. Pro Tools can easily do this.

Comment: I don't use Logic, however, can't it just treat each take as a folder... then you just cut the folder. [Or possibly manually 'folderize' each take first]

Comment: It sounds like he's done 10 drum takes in one session and wants to make one good drum take from sections of 10 takes. So he wants to highlight or select a section of a drum take which means he would need it to select the same section across all the mics. Then he can move them in sync. In Pro Tools you would simply group all the drum channels so you could then select and edit/move the drum mics around as if it's a single audio clip. But I don't know how to do it in Logic or if you can.

Comment: ...& I know how to do it in Cubase - you simply 'cut the folder' & all contents can be manipulated in sync, whatever you want to do with them - & that's without using multi-take track groups, which I imagine are pretty app-specific.

Comment: Haven't used Cubase for around 10 years. There must be a way to do it in Logic. First place I'd look of youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was my fault.
Make sure the region's start at the same place, the desired tracks are in an ACTIVE group with "editing" enable.